# How to get the EPOCH of a concatenated timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how do I get the epoch (UTC time) of a table date field whose time zone is assumed to be GMT and whose hours, min, seconds value is assumed to be '00:00:00'?

e.g.  mytable.DT_GMT has values like '2018-10-16'.

Here's what I've tried so far. Instead of DT_GMT, I've just used '2018-10-16'. I'll replace it with the table field once I have some thing that works.

```
postgres=> select extract(epoch from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE concat('2018-10-16',' 00:00:00.00-00') );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "concat"
LINE 1: ...elect extract(epoch from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE concat('20...
```

Trying something related:

```
postgres=> SELECT TIMESTAMP ('2018-10-16' || ' 00:00:00.00') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'2018-10-16'"
LINE 1: SELECT TIMESTAMP ('2018-10-16' || ' 20:38:40') AT TIME ZONE ...
```

Note that the hours...sec is necessary because without it those values are not what's required.

```
postgres=> SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-10-16' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT';
        timezone
------------------------
 2018-10-15 17:00:00-07
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a string concatenation, you [add them as `date` and `time with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html).

```
test=> select extract(epoch from date '2018-10-16' + time with time zone '00:00:00.00-00');
 date_part  
------------
 1539648000
(1 row)
```

If you're only adding '00:00:00' to make the time zones work, you don't need it with a `date`.

```
test=> select date_part('epoch', date '2018-10-16');
 date_part  
------------
 1539648000

$ date --date '@1539648000' --utc
Tue Oct 16 00:00:00 UTC 2018
```

This is a good reason to store dates and times as their proper type, especially in Postgres which cares a lot about types, rather than as `text`.